# What is the importance of renewing session infomation?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am developing a blog application in codeigniter that has user authorization information.However upon looking at the `config.php` file,i found this two variables

`$config['sess_expiration']     = 7200;`

and

`$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;`

From the docs `'sess_expiration'            = the number of SECONDS you want the session to last.`

and `'sess_time_to_update'     = how many seconds between CI refreshing Session Information`

In the course of `7200` seconds,the app shall receive `24` new session ids.Does this improve security of the application?.

Comment: Generating new session IDs prevents some eavesdropper from using the old session ID.  This is an important part of session security.

Comment: sessions have two components: the server-side data store, and the cookie holding the session's ID on the client. If either are destroyed, then a user's session becomes disconnected and there'll be no way to associate things on either side again. periodically "renewing" either keeps the session alive. plus, as brad mention, there's the security component as well.

Comment: @MarcB There's no need to renew a session ID just to extend the session. I think renewing the ID is purely a security thing. Am I missing something?

Comment: sure there is. e.g. php default sessions are file based, and use file mtime to decide if they're stale or not. stale session files are nuked, and boom. now the user's got a session ID which doesn't exist anymore on the server. Session cookie must also be periodically renewed. If it gets deleted by the client browser, boom, no more link to the server-side session file.

Comment: @MarcB Can't the session be extended without changing the session ID? I don't get why you're saying a session that is about to become stale but gets new activity needs to change its ID

Comment: I never said the ID has to be changed. renewing a session doesn't mean changing its id. it means refreshing the data (however it's stored) so that it doesn't appear to be stale to the cleanup systems.

Comment: Thanks guys.I was hoping to make the app to never renew the session id but now i know better.Thank you.

Comment: The app doesn't necessarily receive 24 new session ID's as it takes a page refresh to generate a new ID.  What it's doing is keeping the session alive for another 7200 seconds though if you are still actively loading pages after 300 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about CodeIgniter specifically, but the reason for changing the session id is usually preventing [session fixation attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation). They consist of someone sending a link with a session id to their target. If this session id is retained after the target logs in, it is possible for the attacker to hijack the session as the id is known. But to mitigate this type of attack, it is enough to change the id upon login. I think CI also updates some metadata at this time, like the last access time and, more importantly, resets the expiration counter, so that the user's session doesn't expire during active site use.